# Windows 10 IoT Internet connection sharing

Tags: raspberry-pi, router, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

Got a Raspberry Pi 2 running Raspbian which shares its PPPoE Ethernet connection via Wi-Fi (basically, serves as a geeky home access point).

Is it possible to obtain this setup using Windows 10 IoT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I heard you can do it with the right Wifi adapter (Windows 10 Iot drivers are limited):

http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2015/08/22/windows-10-iot-core-on-raspberry-pi-2-using-an-internet-shared-connection.aspx